# Adding meta tag titles in each page in drupal7

Tags: drupal-7, metadata, meta-tags

In my drupal site i created pages like page--about-us.tpl.php etc. I need to add metatg 
`<meta name="title" content="ABOUT US">` in pages. Is there any way to do this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Open xtemplate.engine in /themes/engines/xtemplate

Around line 53, where variables are assigned to the template, you'll have a line that starts with

"content" =>

Just above that line, add:

"nodewords" => (module_invoke("nodewords", "get", $node->nid)),

Next, open up xtemplate.xtmpl and add a standard meta keywords tag to the head area, with {nodeword} where the keywords would normally go.

Comment: @ John Smith Thanks for your help. Managed to done it using `function creative_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
$viewport = array(
  '#tag' => 'meta', 
  '#attributes' => array(
    'name' => 'title', 
    'content' => drupal_get_title(),
  ),
);
drupal_add_html_head($viewport, 'viewport');

} `       in templates.php file of theme